# Changing default editor

Tags: linux, bash, editors

There are two ways to change the default editor:

- `update-alternatives --set editor /bin/nano`
- `export EDITOR='/bin/nano'`
  added to `~/.bashrc` (single user) or `/etc/profile.d/` (all users)

Is there any difference / nuance between them? e.g. availability on multiple distros?

---

UPDATE

There is also `select-editor`

Comment: What is the big picture, the final goal? Why do you want to set the default editor for `bash` users on most systems, but not for users of other shells?

Comment: Why not both? set `EDITOR=editor` and configure the alternatives to point to whatever real editor. Covers most bases.

Comment: @muru What is `editor`? Is that just a symlink to something defined by `update-alternatives" tool?

Comment: @Philippos I've removed that bit to avoid going off topic. I concede your point.

Comment: Well, yes, `editor` is a symlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `update-alternatives` is <s>specific to debian</s>
- Changing a users `.bashrc` is a bad idea.  Your users will hate you.
- Writing a file to `/etc/profile.d/` will not affect users of ksh, csh, zsh...
  any settings made in the users `.bashrc` will overwrite your setting.  Which is a good thing.

If `update-alternatives` is available on the target system, that's the way to go.  It should be available on both debian- and redhat-distros.

Otherwise `/etc/profile.d/` is probably your best option.  But you will need to look in other places to configure the not-bash shells.